# How to take ownership of many user roaming profiles at once with powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to set the ownership of many folders within a directory that have a certain modification date, this requires me to use a Foreach-Object. I was able to get all of the names of the folders I want, however, I am not able to use the command prompt commands "takeown" and "icacls" on the folders.

Heres what I tried:

```
Get-ChildItem D:\2008_Profile | 
 ?{$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-163)} |
  ForEach-Object { 
    echo $_.Name
    takeown /f $_.Name /R
    icacls $_.Name /grant administrators:F
}
```

Heres what I get:

```
aan.V2

takeown : ERROR: The system cannot find the file specified.
At line:4 char:1
+ takeown /f $_.Name /R
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (ERROR: The syst...file specified.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError


Successfully processed 0 files; Failed processing 1 files


icacls : aan.V2: The system cannot find the file specified.
At line:5 char:1
+ icacls $_.Name /grant administrators:F
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (aan.V2: The sys...file 
specified.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

note: aan.V2 is a folder name

Comment: replace `$_.Name` with `$_.FullName` to reference things by the full path. Or change your current directory to that of the referenced object.

Comment: Thanks @TheMadTechnician, This worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Question answered in a comment:**

> Replace `$_.Name` with `$_.FullName` to reference things by the full
>   path. Or change your current directory to that of the referenced
>   object. – *TheMadTechnician*